# google drive api Resumable upload error 400 Parse Error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api, fetch

"Multipart upload" is normal but "Resumable upload" is not.

What is wrong with my "code"?

Does the api need to retransmit the file when the user's network is interrupted?

Will the file be retransmitted from the interruption?

sorry my english is poor

```
function uploadPostBlob(selectedFile) {

  //selectFile is File Object
  var metadata = {
    'name': selectedFile.name, // Filename at Google Drive
    'mimeType': selectedFile.mimeType, // mimeType at Google Drive
    'parents': ['root'], // Folder ID at Google Drive
  };
  var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {
    type: 'application/json'
  }));
  form.append('file', selectedFile);

  //https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
  //https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart

  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'

    }),
    body: form,
  }).then((res) => {

    return res.json();

  }).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your script? Is your script the whole script for resumable upload?

Comment: If the user's network is down, the user uploads from the break when the network is restored.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your script works fine. Under this situation, you want to know how to resume when the resumable upload is stopped. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: Is a complete script

Comment: I want to know why "error 400" appears.

Comment: and I want to know how to recover when the recoverable upload stops.

Comment: In your question, there are 2 questions as follows. 1. Your script doesn't work. Your script in your question is the whole script for resumable upload process. You want to know about the reason. 2. You want to know how to resume when the resumable upload is stopped. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the answer for question 1, you can see the detail process of the resumable upload using Drive API at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable). About the answer for question 2, you can see the method at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resume-upload). If these were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I did it according to the document, then I failed.

So I asked questions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you had already checked the official document from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Can you provide valid code? Let me refer